# How to go to next scene using AS3 AIR for Android?

Tags: android, actionscript-3, flash, air

I'm doing a project using Flash CS6..I'm creating an educational game for Android..I'm new with Flash and AIR..I've made a button that supposed to lead it to the next scene..but somehow it didn't work..this is what I used:

```
import flash.desktop.NativeApplication;

stop();

LL_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, nxtScene);
function nxtScene(e:MouseEvent):void
{
   gotoAndPlay(1,"Scene 2");
}
```

The error was:-

```
ArgumentError: Error #2108: Scene Scene 2 was not found.
at flash.display::MovieClip/gotoAndPlay()
at RSFK_fla::MainTimeline/nxtScene()[RSFK_fla.MainTimeline::frame1:17]
```

Please help me! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You probably don't have a Scene that's called Scene 2.

You can check this easily be opening the "actions" panel in your timeline (the actions panel is the editor where you write your code) and check the lower left of the panel. There you can see all the scenes that are accessible from your code.

Comment: I've checked..there is 'Scene 2' on the list..is there anything else I should check?

Comment: Well, you go to frame 1 with gotoAndPlay(1, "scene 2"). Is Scene 2 still available in frame 1?

Comment: Yes, it is..I actually have 3 buttons on the 'Scene 1' which are Exit, Let's Learn and Let's Play button..The Exit button works fine..but not the other two..

Comment: DodgerThud is still probably right. The scene is case sensitive, and also white-space sensitive. So your scene might be called "scene2" or "Scene2" instead of "Scene 2"

Comment: Well I've double checked it..and the name for each scene is correct..hmmm..I don't know what to do anymore..